# Erro ao executar makemigrations no meu projeto django

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando executar o makemigrations no meu projeto django
, mas ele esta retornando erro dizendo que o argumento `default`
não é esperado ou algo do tipo, segue trecho do erro:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dafault'
```

Não sei o que está acontecendo, pois em outros projetos já executei classes com atributos praticamente idênticos sem que erro algum acontecesse.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
class Music(models.Model):
    id_music = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        dafault=uuid.uuid4(),
        editable=True,
        unique=True
    )
```

PS.: Estou usando o Python na versão 3.8.6 e o django na versão 3.1.6

Answer (score 1):

```
class Music(models.Model):
    id_music = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=True,
        unique=True
    )
```

Não precisa chamar a função com *( )*

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Vc tem certeza que escreveu 'default', certo?